# How to con-cat variable inside quotes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want to concat outputFile variable instead of a filename in the below code in python
can anyone help me out?

```
outputFile= 'test.csv'

connection.execute("TRUNCATE travel_staging.upsell_test;"
    "COPY travel_staging.upsell_test FROM 's3://folder/filename' WITH CREDENTIALS "
    "'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'"
    " FORMAT csv DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 DATEFORMAT 'auto' NULL AS 'null' MAXERROR 500 acceptinvchars;")
```

Expected output

```
 TRUNCATE travel_staging.upsell_test;
 COPY travel_staging.upsell_test FROM 's3://folder/test.csv' WITH CREDENTIALS 
 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxx'
 FORMAT csv DELIMITER ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 DATEFORMAT 'auto' NULL AS 'null' MAXERROR 500
```

Comment: Have you considered using a bind variable? They're generally the Right Way to pass data into SQL, without risking hostile values being parsed as additional query content.

Comment: Also, *which specific* dbapi driver are you using? They use slightly different mechanisms.

Comment: To give a contrived-and-not-at-all-tested example, you don't want what happens if `outputFilename=$'\'; DROP DATABASE travel_staging; -- '`.

Comment: ...if you *insist* on doing the wrong thing, I'd probably switch to an f-string, which we have plenty of Q&A entries already discussing, including the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

## To replace a variable in a string

Use `f` strings.

```py
>>> fox = 'quick brown'
>>> dog = 'lazy'
>>> f'the {fox} fox jumps over the {dog} dog'
```

### If you don't need the newlines

Use the `\` to continue the statement on a new line.

```py
>>> 'the quick brown fox jumps \
... over the lazy dog'
'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

### If you do need the new lines

Just have each line on a separate string.

```py
>>> print('\n'.join([
...     'the quick brown fox jumps',
...     'over the lazy dog',
... ]))
the quick brown fox jumps
over the lazy dog
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's answer about how to use the value of `outputFile` instead of hardcoding `filename`. They already have perfectly good multi-line continuation; nothing in that aspect of the code needs to be changed at all.

Comment: (Try it yourself: `print("hello"` on one line, `" cruel "` on the second, `"world")` on the third, and you'll see that they all get concatenated to `print("hello cruel world")`, as you can see at https://ideone.com/P5jSca)

Comment: My point is that you were answering a question that wasn't asked. *Now* you're answering the actual question, but only in the first of the three sections in your answer; the other two are irrelevant.

Comment: ...the demonstration above is that *the OP's code already worked as-is*, except for the replacement.

Comment: (and as for the replacement itself, doing it as string substitution in the OP's context opens you up to SQL injection attacks, so teaching that practice is counterproductive to software security; good-practice alternatives are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python).